# How can I create a table as a select from another database in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to create a table (in my dev db) using a SELECT from a different database?

I want something like:

```
create tmp_table as select * from prod_db.prod_schema.table
```

Is there syntax to do this, or do I need to create a database link first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You have to create a datalink first**.

Oracle cannot query other databases unless a DB link is created. If a DB link exists, as you remarked, you have to do :

```
create tmp_table as select * from prod_schema.table@prod_db
```

Answer (score 4):

@Steve is correct that there has to be a DB Link, but the syntax is:

```
create tmp_table as select * from table@dblink
```

Comment: Oops... got bitten (Didn't have an Oracle DB at hand to test). Corrected my answer, thx...

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to create your indexes.  You can get this for all the tables in your schema with a query like this:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX',u.index_name)
     FROM USER_INDEXES u;
```

Comment: I'll leave that for the dba :)

Comment: lol, if you're going to do that you can just ask your dba to EXP/IMP the schema directly, it will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting `ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command` with @chris's answer, try adding `TABLE` after `CREATE`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM TABLE@DB_LINK;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
AS SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name;
```

Comment: This does not take into account "from a different database"